# Eclipse Code Recommenders Error

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-marketplace

"Code Recommenders Instalation Error"
org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp

I'm using Mars and gettin this error everyday when i try to use "Ctrl + Space".
In only appears once in a day(the first time in the day that i want to use code recommenders).

Eclipse gives me the magical solution to "restart Eclipse", but it doesn't do anything.

I tried to reinstall the eclipse plugin, without success.

Thanks to all for your possible help!

Comment: "Code Recommenders Instalation Error"

org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp

Comment: I think I got the same problem. You can just ignore it, since it wil only be displayed the first time you use the code recommender tool every startup. Till now I have not seen any problems, and everything seems to work perfectly (including the addon itself).

Comment: Yes, i ve been ignoring it the last days, but i really want to find a solution to this.. :/

Answer (score 12):

This error occurs if Code Recommenders cannot resolve its bundle that integrates with Mylyn.

The most likely cause is that you somehow installed Code Recommender's Mylyn completion but don't have (a compatible version of) Mylyn installed.

Do the following to remove the non-functional bundle:

Go to `Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details`. 
In the Installed Software dialog, select the `Code Recommenders Mylyn Integration` entry, press `Uninstall...` and follow the instructions.

Comment: Worked for me. I removed some plugins manually (don‘t use Mylny for example) and somehow missed `org.eclipse.recommenders.mylny.rcp`

Comment: the `Uninstall...` button is greyed out for me

Answer (score 4):

1. into eclipse folder,search for "org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp".
2. Find 2 files "org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature_2.3.0.v20160216-1255" and"org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp_2.3.0.v20160216-1255.jar".
3. Cut to another folder .
4. Del "eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.update"
5. Restart eclipse.
6. Copy the 2 files back to the original folder .
   Try again .

Answer (score 0):

Clean eclipse cache by edit the `eclipse.ini` file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert -clean as the first line.

Or you can do this by making `-clean` key word as an argument.

Don't forget to restore it. that would disable the useful OSGi caching and increase eclipse startup time so make eclipse start in normal mode.